# How can I extract data from SQLite in a server page, and use the data in a different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to make a website using HTML/CSS/JavaScript on the client-side, and use Node.js and SQLite on the server-side.

Below is the code I wrote in 'app.js' which is my server page.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
app.use(express.static('public'))


async function getDBConnection(){
    const db = await sqlite.open({
        filename: "author.db",
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    });
    return db;
}

app.get('/', async function(req, res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let authors = await db.all("SELECT * from author");
    await db.close();
})

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server on! http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

I'm trying to extract the data from the author.db, and use the extracted data in a separate javascript file, which is the 'script.js' file. Is there any way for me to do this? I've tried putting two script tags in my index.html file, but an error appears indicating that the server cannot locate the app.js file.

Below is my code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
    </head>
    <body id = "i_body">
        <div class = "fpage">
            <main>
            </main>
        </div>
        <script src = "app.js></script>
        <script src = "./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your app.js is your node server. It runs as a backend server - you don't include it as a reference on your front end. Your front-end has to make a request to the backend server (usually using a library like axios) which will fetch the data that the backend provides you. So in your get '/' section you will want to return a json response with your records. Then on your client side, use a library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser) to fetch the data and then use it how you like.

Edit:

Your server code can look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
app.use(express.static('public'))


async function getDBConnection(){
    const db = await sqlite.open({
        filename: "author.db",
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    });
    return db;
}

app.get('/api/authors', async function(req, res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let authors = await db.all("SELECT * from author");
    await db.close();
    return res.json(authors)
})

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server on! http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Notice that you are now serving the json off an api endpoint - in this case `/api/authors` although this can be anything.

Put your client files in the `public` folder - so `index.html` and `script.js` should be there. Your index.html file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id = "i_body">
        <div class = "fpage">
            <main>
            </main>
        </div>
        <script src = "./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that I have included the CDN for the axios library, and removed the reference to the node part in your client. Your `script.js` can look like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/authors').then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
```

Here you can see I'm using the axios library to call the backend with the endpoint that I mentioned before `/api/authors`. It gets the json as `res.data`. At that point you can do whatever you want to it. Hope that helps!

Comment: So, to clarify your response, I have to return a json response in my node server and use the json in my client side?

Comment: That's correct. Think of your backend as like a standalone application. It responds to requests and serves up json. Your client is another separate application. Using axios, make a get request to http://localhost:3000/  - This will then hit your node server and it will serve up the json, which will be received by your front end javascript file. Once you have that json then you can do whatever you want with it in your client. Does that make sense?